# while accessing iCloud contacts in my app results in crash in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, abaddressbook

I want to access my address book contacts in my app,i am successfully able to retrieve all contacts from my address book but if sync my i-cloud account in my iPad,then my address book get updated from my i-cloud contacts also,and if now i access my contacts it results in crash.
Kindly help me ,i am completely stuck don't know what to do.
I can easily access the address book contacts but once it get synced from i-cloudand after that i fetch the address book,it results in crash and give me bad excess error.

Here is the code that i used to fetch contacts.

```
+(NSArray *)getAllContacts
{

    CFErrorRef *error = nil;


    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Fetching contact info ----> ");
#endif


        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];


        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {
            MContact *contacts = [MContact new];

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get First Name and Last Name

            contacts.firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            contacts.lastName =  (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (!contacts.firstName) {
                contacts.firstName = @"";
            }
            if (!contacts.lastName) {
                contacts.lastName = @"";
            }


            NSMutableArray *contactEmails = [NSMutableArray new];
            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); i++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, i);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [contactEmails addObject:contactEmail];
                // NSLog(@"All emails are:%@", contactEmails);

            }

            if([contactEmails count]==0){

            }
            else{
                [contacts setemails:contactEmails];
                [items addObject:contacts];

            }




#ifdef DEBUG
#endif




        }
        return items;



    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
#endif
        return NO;


    }


}
```

Comment: This thread helps me to fix my crash issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651715/what-abrecordcopyvalue-can-return-solving-a-bad-access

Comment: This thread helps me to fix my crash issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651715/what-abrecordcopyvalue-can-return-solving-a-bad-access

Comment: [This thread helps me to fix my crash issue,][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651715/what-abrecordcopyvalue-can-return-solving-a-bad-access

Answer (score 0):

Did you found exactly where in your code the crash append ? If it is in your "for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)" loop, may be you have an issue on 1 contact only...

PS 1, you should remove line 7 : ....ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions, as you need to check for authorization first....

PS 2, did you really need only contacts from default source ? What about if user have also contact from Lotus Notes or other gmail....

Comment: it crashes on this line              contacts.firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue but not sure it will solve your crash... You should replace your **_*bridge*** by **_bridge_transfer** :

```
contacts.firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Do the same for lastname....

If it did not solve the crash, I would suggest to try isolate the "person" in your AB witch crash, and try to skip it in your "for loop". This should help us to know if it is only a problem with this person or if it is related to the number of person to load. In my ABLocation App, I know some users have >500 contacts, and they have no PB...